# Clean way to implement a controller in PHP MVC

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, controller

I'm a beginner in PHP (But I have some Java EE background) I want to create a simple Blog, but I want to do it by using PHP OOP MVC and good/best practices, I'm still thinking how to do things, but I'm really stuck at the idea of how to implement a Controller, and how will it communicate with the views, I find it very different than Java EE, and I don't know where or how to start.

Let me tell you how I'm planning to make it work, at least till the "controller" part :

- Ultimately the design will be :

`DB <-> DAO <-> Service <-> Controller <-> View.`
But I'll make it simple for the example.

Here we have a DAO class to communicate with the DB.

```
class UserDAO {

    private $db;

    // something like this by injecting the database object
    public function __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function findUserById($id) {
        $req = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $id");
        //.. etc
        //.. don't worry about the syntax, what matters is that we're returning the user Object that we found.
        return $user;

    }
}
```

The controller will be something like this :

```
class Controller {

    private $dao;

    public function __construct(UserDAO $dao) {
        $this->dao = $dao;
    }

    public function loadUser($id) {
        return $this->dao->findUserById($id);
    }
}
```

Now, let's say that I have a `index.php` view file, how can I show the `$user` infos on the page, or sending data from view to controller later if I want to save a `$user`, by using best practices, not just like `require` the views inside controller functions etc..

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Here is a good read, wirth an example of what you're trying to do. http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2005/11/03/mvc_controller.html

Comment: @Kray I've already seen that topic, it didn't help.

Comment: Why not use an open source `PHP` framework to build your blog instead of trying to create your own framework?

Comment: @TheAlpha I want to do it the hard way to learn some tricky parts about PHP.

Comment: There are lot of PHP MVC frameworks. (Laravel, Symfony & CakePHP). They have easy ways to implement the MVC System. why you don't use it?

Comment: @K.Suthagar As I said just before, I need to learn PHP the hard way first! And when I'm comfortable using it then I'll use a framework.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a controller function to require using an output buffer.

```
/**
 * Renders a view file as a PHP script.
 *
 * This method treats the view file as a PHP script and includes the file.
 * It extracts the given parameters and makes them available in the view file.
 * The method captures the output of the included view file and returns it as a string.
 *
 * This method should mainly be called by view renderer or [[renderFile()]].
 *
 * @param string $_file_ the view file.
 * @param array $_params_ the parameters (name-value pairs) that will be extracted and made available in the view file.
 * @return string the rendering result
 */
public function renderPhpFile($_file_, $_params_ = [])
{
    ob_start();
    ob_implicit_flush(false);
    extract($_params_, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
    require($_file_);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Taken from https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/View.php#L149